# helm diff release "Error: unknown flag: --template"

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

I was trying to use helm plugin `diff` but when I was trying to find the diff between the release it is throwing me an error

Here is my **helm diff command**

```
helm diff release myhelloworld myhelloworld2
```

```
Error: unknown flag: --template

Error: plugin "diff" exited with error
```

Here are my **releases**

```
helm list -a
```

```
NAME            NAMESPACE   REVISION
myhelloworld    default     3       
myhelloworld2   default     1
```

Is there anything wrong with my **helm diff** command?

Comment: Which `helm version` are you using?

Comment: I am using helm v3.4.0

Comment: Try updating the plugin: `helm plugin update diff`. Does this solve it?

Comment: I updated the diff plugin as you suggested but it did not solve the issue. Do you any more suggestions?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, @RahulWagh how did you solve it?